# PIC16F877A timer1 interrupt time is not as expected

Tags: c, embedded, pic

Implemented interrupt function on TIMER1 on PIC16F877A MCU on [PIC-DIP40](http://hobbycomponents.com/images/forum/PIC16F877A_Development_Board_Schematic_1024.png) development board. Configured the timer Prescaler to `1` and auto preload value to `55536` so that the interrupt time is `0.01s`. Using a counter of `100` to count `1s` interval. The Fosc is `4Mhz`. So my calculation is :

```
interrupt time = (4 / Fosc) * (65536 - 55536) = (4/4000000) * (65536 - 55536) = 0.01 s
```

And used a counter of `100` to generate a `1s` interval.
Currently, I have no oscilloscope to test the actual 1s interval so, I am blinking an LED (LED2) on the timer interrupt and another LED (LED1) on the same time interval `1s` using `__delay_ms(1000);` function.

So as expected the two LEDs will blink synchronously (Turn ON and OFF at the same Time). But for some first iterations, they blink synchronously. After some iterations, there is a clear difference in time between their blinking time (Turning ON and OFF time). After several minutes the difference is almost 1s. **So the timer interrupt is not working as expected.**

So is my calculation wrong for interrupt time or I am missing something in the timer1 configuration?

**The overall goal is to generate a 1s time interval and test the validity without using an oscilloscope.**

Here is my code :

```
// CONFIG
#pragma config FOSC = HS        // Oscillator Selection bits (HS oscillator)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = OFF      // Brown-out Reset Enable bit (BOR disabled)
#pragma config LVP = OFF        // Low-Voltage (Single-Supply) In-Circuit Serial Programming Enable bit (RB3 is digital I/O, HV on MCLR must be used for programming)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data EEPROM Memory Code Protection bit (Data EEPROM code protection off)
#pragma config WRT = OFF        // Flash Program Memory Write Enable bits (Write protection off; all program memory may be written to by EECON control)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Flash Program Memory Code Protection bit (Code protection off)

#include <xc.h>
#include <pic16f877a.h>
#define _XTAL_FREQ  4000000

#define LED1_ON PORTDbits.RD7 = 0
#define LED1_OFF PORTDbits.RD7 = 1 
#define LED2_ON PORTDbits.RD6 = 0
#define LED2_OFF PORTDbits.RD6 = 1 

#define LED2_TOGGLE PORTDbits.RD6 = ~PORTDbits.RD6

uint16_t preloadValue  = 55536 ; 
uint16_t counter  = 0 ; 
uint16_t secCounter1 = 100 ; 

void io_config() {
    TRISD  &= ~((1 << _PORTD_RD7_POSITION) | (1 << _PORTD_RD6_POSITION)) ; //RD7 and RD6 are output LEDs
}

void timer1_init(){
    TMR1 = preloadValue ; //loading the preload value
    T1CON &= ~((1 << _T1CON_T1CKPS1_POSN) | (1 << _T1CON_T1CKPS0_POSN) | (1 << _T1CON_TMR1CS_POSN)) ; //prescalar is 1 clock is Fosc
    T1CONbits.TMR1ON = 1 ; //timer 1 is ON
    LED2_ON ; 
}

void interrupt_en_configure(){
    INTCON |=  (1 << _INTCON_GIE_POSITION) | (1 << _INTCON_PEIE_POSITION) ; //global and peripheral interrupt on
    PIE1 |= _PIE1_TMR1IE_MASK ;  //timer 1 interrupt enable
    TMR1IF = 0 ; //clearing interupt flag
}

void __interrupt() ISR(){
    if(TMR1IF){
        counter ++  ; 
        if (counter == secCounter1){
            counter = 0 ;
            LED2_TOGGLE ; 
        }
        
        TMR1 = preloadValue ;
        TMR1IF = 0 ; 
    }
}

void main(void) {
    io_config();
    interrupt_en_configure() ; 
    timer1_init() ;
    
    while (1) {
        LED1_ON ; 
        __delay_ms(1000);
        LED1_OFF ;
        __delay_ms(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your equation shouldn't mix frequencies and times, those are different units. `1/f = t` yeah? Convert everything to time if you wish to calculate timer cycles.

Comment: Ahmad Yeaseen Khan, `while (1) { LED1_ON ;  __delay_ms(1000);  LED1_OFF ;  __delay_ms(1000);  }` takes slightly more than 2000 ms.  Why not expect drift? Or perhaps the `__delay_ms(1000);` is not quite 1000.0 ms?  "So the timer interrupt is not working as expected." may really be the `while` loop is not working as expected.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica then is there any way to calculate how much more time it will take? Currently experimenting without oscilloscopes so, feeling "blind" about small time intervals.

Comment: @Lundin I think `(4/Fosc)` is changing `Hz` to `s`.

Comment: @AhmadYeaseenKhan No, not in the long term. [Segal's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segal%27s_law).  The `while()` has to account for all interrupts service time too.

Comment: @AhmadYeaseenKhan IMO, you are better off not toggling the LEDs in the ISR.  Instead record time.  Let the main job loop routines inquire of elapsed time to toggle the LEDs. If I knew the overall goal more, a better explanation could be offered.

Comment: The blinking done under interrupt, and the blinking done in `main` have different "reload" times (ie dead time between each period). And your timer would be more accurate if it is configured to free run.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica The overall goal is to generate a `1s` time interval and test the validity without using an oscilloscope.

Comment: Try `uint16_t counter  = 0 ;` --> `volatile uint16_t counter  = 0 ;` and `__delay_ms(1000);` --> `uint16_t t0, t1 = counter; do { t0 = t1; t1 = counter; } while (t1 >= t0);`. to sync the `while` loop delay to the ISR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__delay_ms()` delays by running an empty loop, but it commonly cannot be exact. You would need to look into the actual machine code that is run to calculate the real delay. BTW, this is not rocket science and a great learning task. (Been there, done that.)

Now the rest of your loop (LED switching, looping) adds to this. Therefore, your pure software driven blinker is not exact.

However, your interrupt driven blinker is not, too. You reset the timer at the end of the ISR, after several clock cycles have passed. You need to take this into account, and don't forget the interrupt latency. Even worse, depending on the conditional statement, the reset happens at different times after the timer overflow.

Producing exact timing is difficult, especially with such a simple device.

The solution is to avoid software at all for the reset of the timer. Please read chapter 8 of the data sheet and use the capture/compare/PWM module to reset the timer on the appropriate value.

The worst thing that could still happen is some jitter, just because the ISR might have different latencies. But the timer runs as exactly as your system's crystal. In average your LED will blink correctly.

Anyway, if your timing requirements are not that hard, consider to live with some inaccuracy. Then use the most simple solution you like best.

Answer (score 2):

You should not expect them to operate synchronously for the following reasons:

- First you do not know how `__delay_ms()` is implemented or any "promises" of precision it may make - it is certainly not using TIMER1, because you are controlling that.  In fact the [documentation](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/16-Bit-Language-Tools-Libraries-DS50001456K.pdf) gives some implementation details, and you *really* cannot expect precision.
- Secondly, even if `__delay_ms()` were both accurate and synchronous, you are invoking it in a loop with the software overhead of the loop, function call and whatever you are doing to toggle the LED.  That is a few cycles on every iteration that do not affect the interrupt interval which is locked to the hardware, and independent of the software timing.

The issue of precision of `__delay_ms()` is in fact addressed in [this Microchip support article](https://microchipsupport.force.com/s/article/Delay-functions-in-XC16-and-XC8-and-their-functionaility) where it starts:

> If an accurate delay is required, or if there are other tasks that can be performed during the delay, then using a timer to generate an interrupt is the best way to proceed.

In this case you should trust your code over the library provided delay which is intentionally crude (because it does not use up a valuable H/W timer resource).